# Swagger works only with an apicontroller, not with an mvc controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, asp.net-apicontroller

I am using swagger for my api documentation but it seems that swagger only detact 
only those class that inherit ApiController not those classes those inherit 
basecontroller Am i right? Or there is some way to make swagger work with mvc 
controller.

Example:-

```
Public myController:ApiController
```

Works fine but

```
 Public myController:BaseController
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using swashbuckle? , and that should be working fine, I use it all the time.

Answer (score -1):

Swagger is a specification for documenting REST API. It specifies the format (URL, method, and representation) to describe REST web services. So you won't use directly, you can use api(controller) in your controller.